# How does webpack bundling work when I don't see the output in my project directory?

Tags: webpack, bundler

I'm learning redux but have trouble understanding how webpack works. A lot of the examples from the redux [page](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/counter) have an index.html that has the this script:

```
<script src="/static/bundle.js"></script>
```

Yet I can't find this.bundle.js file anywhere, nor is there a static folder. I know that the webpack.config.js has an output to this, but when is this realized? How am I able to `npm init` and `npm start` this project and see it locally but not see the static/bundle.js file in my project folder?

Comment: You need to run `webpack` from the command line to build a bundle.  But it depends on what scripts are wired up in the package.json

Comment: so if I haven't run webpack yet, how can I be seeing the app work when I go to localhost?

Comment: It might be configured to run within the `npm start` script. My guess without seeing your configuration data is it's using `webpack-dev-server` which serves resources from memory and not from disk.